# enter password using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to restrict accessing `write.php` using password, but the password should be enetring using jquery ajax method on another page (index.php).

index.php

```
<div id="btnsNo">
<img class="btNo" id='n0' src="btns/num0.png" alt="num">
<img class="btNo" id='n1' src="btns/num1.png" alt="num">
<img class="btNo" id='n2' src="btns/num2.png" alt="num">
<img class="btNo" id='n3' src="btns/num3.png" alt="num">
<img class="btNo" id='n4' src="btns/num4.png" alt="num">
<img class="btNo" id='n5' src="btns/num5.png" alt="num">
</div>
```

js

```
pass = '';
$('.btNo').click(function(){
    $a = $(this).attr('id');
    $b = $a.substring(1);
    pass = pass + $b;
    alert (pass);  // works well till here
    $.ajax({
        url : 'pass.php',
        type : 'post',
        data : { pass : pass }
});
});
```

pass.php

```
$pass01 = 1405;
$pass02 = $_POST['pass'];
if ($pass01 = $pass02){
header('Location: write.php');
}
```

I clicked on `.btnNo` so `pass` is `1405` - but nothing happens. I expected to redirect to `write.php`.

Comment: You can't use header redirection with Ajax responses.

Comment: did you open your php tags?

Comment: @Juhana, are you sure ? What about the solution bellow. I will try

Comment: @niko, Yes, I oopened and closed them properly

Comment: @user182196 Yes, I'm sure. You can redirect the Ajax response at best. Note that the solution below doesn't use headers. (I'm not saying what you're trying to do is impossible, just that it's not possible with headers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
if ($pass01 == $pass02){
    echo "1";
}else{
   echo "0";
 }
```

script:

```
$(function(){ 
 pass = '';
 $('.btNo').click(function(){
    $a = $(this).attr('id');
    $b = $a.substring(1);
    pass = pass + $b;
    alert (pass);  // works well till here
    $.ajax({
        url : 'pass.php',
        type : 'post',
        data : { pass : pass }
     }).done(function( data ) {
             if(data==1){
                window.location='write.php';
             }
     });
   });
 });
```